# How can I end survey depending on answer SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, branch, survey

I have a survey with several questions and what I want is to end survey depending on answer.
Like, if I have question #1 (answers: Yes, no) and answer to it No, I want survey to finish. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an out of the box solution you could implement the use of branching logic. The catch is the branching logic requires you to select a question to jump to. Often times I would include an optional question at the end such as "Optionally, please provide your name." or "Optionally, please provide any comments you may have regarding..." and this has fit my needs.

If this is not sufficient you are probably looking at a custom solution with maybe using Javascript / jQuery to navigate to different questions on button click or maybe even go as far as custom ASP.NET pages to handle the survey itself.

Comment: Actually I googled a bit around this problem and what everywhere was written is that I can come up with some optional question and jump to that question. but it kinda is not the solution I'm looking for. Is there any other solution??

Comment: Out of the box - probably not. You would at a minimum be looking at some javascript to jump around the pages if not custom aspx page to programmatically complete the survey if there isn't a way to do it through JavaScript. 

I couldn't find anything online but I did a quick check using SharePoint Manager and found that the Survey Lists have a field called "Completed." Theoretically, on your custom page you would do a sort of data validation to check which value was selected and based on that you can either go to the next question or set that field to TRUE or whatever the appropriate value is.